# Lightning action(Email & Task) buttons not showing on Lead

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, page-layout, leads, quickaction

I have the following configuration set  and still Email and Task buttons not showing in the chatter lightning Lead Object:

1- Deliverability = All Emails

2- Task Has a record type

3- Feed Tracking is turned On for Lead Object

4- I have add Email and Task button on the Lead page layout in both sections 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions' and 'Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher' ,
 and made sure that im viewing the right page layouts

5- I add Email and Task button to the Global Publisher Layout in both sections 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions' and 'Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher'

6- I do have Chatter Settings -> Enable Actions in the Publisher -> set to true

here screen shots

Screenshot Number 1

[image]

Screenshot Number 2

[image]

Screenshot Number 3

[image]

Screenshot Number 4

[image]

Screenshot Number 5

[image]

Screenshot Number 6

[image]

but nothing is working

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I needed to add the 'Activities' lightning standard component to the page instead of the 'Chatter' component.

Please follow below steps:
1. Go to Lead record details Page  >> click on Setup Icon >> select Edit Page. (it redirects to the lightning app builder page setup)
2. Search for 'Activities' component and drag to the Page where ever you want to display.
3. Save the page and Go to any lead record detail page.

Now you can see the Email / New Task buttons as below.

Answer (score -1):

Did you also dragged and drop in this section? (lead layout)
[image]

Comment: Yes i did that, and if you look  I have as screenshot number 4, not working

Comment: Based on your answer it doesn't seems that you actually look properly at my screenshot it would have save you a couple of hours (or days based on when you post your answer) as my screenshot was the layout page